# Set SQL Server Management Studio Settings via the Registry

Tags: sql-server, ssms, registrykey

I am trying to find out how one can enforce settings of the SQL Server Management Studio globally via the registry. We have a small query in place which should in theory do that, however it only does so in the current session and obviously only when the queries are executed.

Furthermore we have faced the problem that, due to internal updates, certain settings are being reset to their standard values, which causes problems with certain other applications we are working with, which is why we are trying to force the settings globally and as easy as possible, meaning registry entries in a best case scenario.

Upon checking the registry I've realized that there is an identical folder structure present to each setting contained in SSMS, however these only contain the standard values for the settings as well as some keys which define what the settings window looks like, and trying out certain values hasn't worked either.

Has anyone had any experience with this and can tell me if what we are trying to achieve is possible and, hopefully, feasible?

The settings I need are:

- Query Execution > SQL Server > Advanced > SET_NOCOUNT = checked
- Query Execution > SQL Server > ANSI > SET ANSI_NULLS = unchecked
- Query Results > SQL Server > General > Default destination for results: = Results to text

(Note that we are using SSMS 18.0 in our Server environments)

What I've tried:
As mentioned we have queries in place which should do the expected, but they only do that while in the active session. I have scoured the internet for solutions with registry keys or powershell commands, with no luck. There's also the "Import/Export Settings" function which seemingly does not do anything at all though, unless I have used it wrong.

Comment: I suspect you have an XY problem ... Why? Because no one, literally no one, has required to do that in the history of SQL Server... that aside add TSQL SET NOCOUNT ON; SET ANSI_NULLS ON;

Comment: If you "need" ANSI_NULLS to be off for "correct" behaviour, you're fixing the problem in the wrong place. Some time ago MS was threatening to remove the option and it would only ever be on, and there are a number of features of the product which only work when it's on. You could continue fighting against the tide or *fix the underlying broken logic* that you should have been aware needs fixing for decades at this point.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever
 is 100% correct (I miss-read and thought you were setting SET ANSI_NULLS ON (AS IT SHOULD BE!). Fix the actual problem, not the symptoms.

Comment: Create a simple registry listener and see what settings are changed. But if someone opens ssms and manually change them, I think you are smoked anyway. Why do you need those specific settings anyway

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The problem we are currently facing is that, while the both of you are correct, the developer of said other application is aware of that but chooses to ignore that problem for now and "face it when microsoft truly decides to change to that setting". This means that, while it is obviously stupid to do so, we are forced to use these settings as is until the other software developer decides that it is enough of a problem to act...

Comment: *"the developer of said other application is aware of that but chooses to ignore that problem for no"* Perhaps you should stop using them and find a supplier that actually properly updates their programs. You'd be surprised how quickly a supplier can sometimes *fix* a problem when they are threatened with losing revenue because they **won't** fix it.

Comment: "the developer of said other application is aware of that but chooses to ignore that problem for now and "face it when microsoft truly decides to change to that setting"" - that sounds negligent.

Comment: Just do `EXEC sys.sp_configure N'user options', N'21352'` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-user-options-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @ThomA While that might be true it isn't exactly in my jurastiction to do so

Comment: @MitchWheat Aye it is, though sadly we don't really have an alternative

Comment: *"true it isn't exactly in my jurastiction to do so"* then escalate to whomever's it is. Honestly it sounds like that developer *should* be cut; find a new one, there are always alternatives (even if that means doing it in house).

Comment: @Charlieface I shall try that, on paper this should do it, just need to see about automating it in a given interval so that we can ensure the settings are always correct

Comment: @ThomA That developer is too integral to our company and what we do as that we could completely cut them out over one negligence. Sure it's not ideal but just terminating our ongoing partnership over something as small as that would be making a mountain over a molehill _at best_. I'll try the suggestion of Charlieface and go from there.

Comment: *Is* it "small" when you upgrade to SQL Server 20XX and the application doesn't work at all any more, due to a feature being removed that was warned about 10+ years prior? 

Comment: @ThomA Fact is kicking our dev isn't in the cards for our company so arguing about it isn't going to solve my problem either. I've got my hands tied so i need to find a workaround for it an roll with it